# UIActivityViewController: tint color of presented view controllers

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

In an app I use white as the main tint color. If the user opens the `UIActivityViewController`, I set the tint color for the controller to the standard iOS blue. This works great for the activity view itself but when one wants to send a mail, the tint color is not blue but white again.

It would be great to have a way to set the tint color of the presented views. Is there one?

Opening a `MFMailComposeViewController` and setting the tint color to blue also has an effect on the displayed `UIActionSheet`, not so if the `MFMailComposeViewController` is opened from within an `UIActivityViewController`.

See screenshots for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egnTm.png

Edit: This is what I do for adding the tint color to the `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:activities];
activityController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];`
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

The best what you can do is to set window's tint color to system blue or any tint color you wish on UIActivityViewController just before you present it and then change window's tint color back to original just before you dismiss it. That will work. This is how I do it:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = Styles.color.systemBlue
```

and then

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = Styles.color.tint
```

Comment: Thanks! For those who wonder when `then` is: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = .systemBlue` in the completion block of the present func and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the Cancel and Send buttons of the mail share controller being blue no matter what I tried. I found that tweaking the navbar appearance wasn't doing the trick. So I used this...

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
```

I do this in an "Appearance" class I have that is called on load and sets all of the global appearances. For the navigation bar color, if you need to change that on the fly before presenting your share controller (UIActivityViewController), you can do it in the completion block when you first present your controller. For example:

```
[self presentViewController:[self _shareController] animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourNavBarColor]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not managed to get this to work at all, but have you considered the alternative - leaving the text white and changing the navbar background colour so they show up, e.g. with:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```

This seems to work for the buttons on the navbar for the Mail and Twitter sharing screens.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your app will use this UINavigationBar as default

`UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green`

try this

Answer (score -2):

Set the tintColor on your UIActivityViewController after initializing but before presenting.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:activities];

//Set the tint color on just the activity controller as needed here before presenting
[activityController.view setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Of course this is exactly what I do. Hence, that doesn't help me.